# Glassfish Windows Server 2008 R2 Deploy Issue

Tags: glassfish-3, windows-server-2008-r2, connection-reset

I am using glassfish 3.1 (build 43). When I deploy an application either through the admin console or using the asadmin deploy command, glassfish server stops and I get an error "Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?" (on the asadmin command line console) and error 101 (connection reset error) on the admin console.

The same deployment works on windows XP and Windows 7. Are there any socket timeout settings which need to be configured or something specific to Windows 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the root cause of the issue. While deploying the application the glassfish encountered a jvm crash. After having a look at the generated error file I found that the oracle driver installation was incorrectly done on that machine.
On installing the oracle driver properly, I was able to deploy my application war file. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you configured a different port number for administrative access, something other than 4848. If this is the case, you have to specify the port in your asadmin command by:

```
asadmin deploy --port 7878 --host localhost foo.war
```